# Combinations of all sub array elements without repeats

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I have "attributes" from database. Each attribute has many values. Now I want to mix these values to create unique combinations.

example of input:

```
$a = array(
    35=>array('green','red','brown'),
    36=>array('fox','house','dog')
);
```

output - all possible combinations of second dimensions's elements. example output below:

```
$output = array(
    array(35=>'green',36=>'fox'),
    array(35=>'green',36=>'house'),
    array(35=>'green',36=>'dog'),
    array(35=>'red',36=>'fox'),
    array(35=>'red',36=>'house'),
    array(35=>'red',36=>'dog'),
    array(35=>'brown',36=>'fox'),
    array(35=>'brown',36=>'house'),
    array(35=>'brown',36=>'dog'),
);
```

my function without recurrence:

```
function myfunction($a){

    $keys = array_keys($a);
    $result = array();

    if(count($keys)==0){
        $result = array();
    }
    elseif(count($keys)==1){
        $k = $keys[0];
        foreach($a[$k] as $v){
            $result[] = array($k=>$v);
        }
    }
    elseif(count($keys)==2){
        $k1 = $keys[0];
        $k2 = $keys[1];
        foreach($a[$k1] as $v1){
            foreach($a[$k2] as $v2){
                $result[] = array($k1=>$v1,$k2=>$v2);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif(count($keys)==3){
        $k1 = $keys[0];
        $k2 = $keys[1];
        $k3 = $keys[2];
        foreach($a[$k1] as $v1){
            foreach($a[$k2] as $v2){
                foreach($a[$k3] as $v3){
                    $result[] = array($k1=>$v1,$k2=>$v2,$k3=>$v3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('To much keys', 1);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: So you have a multidimensional array `$a` with the values where you want to create all combinations out of it? Should the combination always be with 2 values or only one value from each array? (e.g. if you have 3 arrays every combination should have 3 values or 2?)

Comment: The number of elements in each combination equals number of array keys in first dimension. One value from each "subarray" (array from second dimension).

Comment: You have this question now twice on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29120826/3933332 I think you can delete the other one, since you posted this one first on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

So what does this code do?

1. How many combinations are there?

So first the question how many combinations are there and the answer is you have to multiply the amount of every array with each other.

So (c = amount<sup>1</sup>):

> c<sub>array 1</sub> * c<sub>array 2</sub> * ... * c<sub>array n</sub>

And specific for your example:

> c<sub>array 1</sub> * c<sub>array 2</sub> **=** 3 * 3 **=** 9

<sub>*<sup>1</sup> And if you wonder why I chose `c` for amount, because of the function `count()` in php</sub>

2. Getting all combinations

How do we get now all combinations with the length of the amount of all arrays?

Well pretty simple, we just loop through all combinations (at the start just an empty combination (`[] == array()`)) which we already have with the next array until we get the desired length which we want, in this case the last iteration of the last array.

So as an example:

```
Array with the elements (Empty array is '[]'):

[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
]
```

```
                               //new combinations for the next iteration
                               |
array NAN*:

    Combinations:
                  - []         |  -> []
                                  |
array 1 [1,2]:       -------------
                    |             |
    Combinations:   v             v
                  - []    + 1  |  -> [1]  
                  - []    + 2  |  -> [2]   
                                  |
array 2 [3,4]:       -------------
                    |             |
    Combinations:   v             v
                  - []    + 3  |  -> [3]
                  - []    + 4  |  -> [4]
                  - [1]   + 3  |  -> [1,3]
                  - [1]   + 4  |  -> [1,4]
                  - [2]   + 3  |  -> [2,3]
                  - [2]   + 4  |  -> [2,4]     
                               //^ All combinations here
```

<sub>* NAN: not a number</sub>

So as you can see in the above example we now have all combinations with the length of the amount of all arrays which we have.

But to get only the combinations with the desired length we are overwriting the result array each iteration, so that at the end only the combinations with the expected length are in the results array.

code:

```
<?php

    $data = [
            35 => ["green", "red", "brown"],
            36 => ["fox", "house", "dog"]
        ];

    $combinations = [[]];
    $comKeys = array_keys($data);


    for ($count = 0; $count < count($comKeys); $count++) {
        $tmp = [];
        foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
            foreach ($data[$comKeys[$count]] as $v2)
                $tmp[] = $v1 + [$comKeys[$count] => $v2];

        }
        $combinations = $tmp;
    }

    print_r($combinations);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [35] => green
            [36] => fox
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [35] => green
            [36] => house
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [35] => green
            [36] => dog
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [35] => red
            [36] => fox
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [35] => red
            [36] => house
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [35] => red
            [36] => dog
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [35] => brown
            [36] => fox
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [35] => brown
            [36] => house
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [35] => brown
            [36] => dog
        )

)
```

Comment: This is indeed the best solution, no recursion is needed. Please note that not all servers have the latest PHP and will not support the new array syntax. This might baffle some people.

Comment: works perfectly. Now, I am going to to study how this works. Thanks a lot dude! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this: https://gist.github.com/jwage/11193216

or

use the code bellow:

```
<?php
$attributes = [
    [
        'P', 'M', 'G', 'XG'
    ],
    [
        'Vermelho', 'Amarelo', 'Verde'
    ],
];



function array_mix($leftItems, $rightItems)
{
    $results   = [];
    foreach ($leftItems as $leftItem) {
        foreach ($rightItems as $key => $rightItem) {
            $results[] = array_merge((array) $leftItem, (array) $rightItem);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$y = $attributes[0];

foreach($attributes as $key => $attrs) {
    if(isset($attributes[$key + 1]) && is_array($attributes[$key + 1])) {
        $y = array_mix($y, $attributes[$key + 1]);
    }
}

var_dump($y);
```